# Scraping one html element into another

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to collect url from a list on a table in R. But table is a html element into web page, so xpath doesn't work adequately. I obtain the following result:

```
> doc<-read_html(url("http://www.bibliotecanacional.gov.co/rnbp/directorio-de-bibliotecas-publicas"))
> v<-toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath='//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Ejemplo2_GridviewConCSSFriendly1_GridViewJedis_LinkButton1_0"]'))
> v
[1] ""
```

In the image, you can see how I extract xpath by inspection of url element.

[Extraction of xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI251.png)

I will be grateful with your help. Thanks.

Comment: an element with that `id` doesn't exist on that page.

Comment: eLRuLL, I added image showing how I extract xpath. You can see id there. This doesn't exist in source code of that page, that is my problem.

Comment: sorry, I meant that it doesn't exist on that "request". That information is loaded dynamically, actually from [this request](http://190.102.160.5/DIRECTORIORNBP/DirectorioRnbp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That page contains an iframe..so you need to switch to the iframe first before you could get the element from that iframe.

It has an iframe with title: Libros digitales y aplicaciones producidas BNC

Not sure how to do that using what you're using, but you might be able to look that up easily in here.